# Notification icon doesn't show

Tags: notifications, firefox-os

I have a little problem with my app, it seems that notifications don't show the icon. According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/icon#Firefox_OS_notes there is a bug in Firefox OS with relative paths, but none of the fixes it list have worked for me. I have tested it in both device and emulator.
The app I'm developing is packaged and privileged, Can that be a problem?

I'm using something like this:

```
function showNotification(title,text) {
    var icon = window.location.origin + "/icon.png";
    new Notification(title, {body: text}, {icon: icon});
}
```

The app is compatible with Firefox OS 1.2 and later.

Answer (score 3):

> One particular Firefox OS **issue** is that you *can* pass a path to an icon to use in the notification, but if the app is packaged you **cannot use** a relative path like `/my_icon.png`. You also **can't use** `window.location.origin + "/my_icon.png"` because `window.location.origin` is **`null`** in packaged apps.
>
> The manifest origin field fixes this, but it is **only available** in `Firefox OS 1.1+`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Notification/icon

However, one possible solution is to encode the image into an [base64](/questions/tagged/base64) [url](/questions/tagged/url) within packaged apps. You can receive `base64` encoded images from an external resource and pass them directly to the [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification) too.

Example [png](/questions/tagged/png) encoder using [canvas](/questions/tagged/canvas):

```
 function createIcon(iconURL) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     let canvas, ctx, image;

     canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
     ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
     image = new Image();

     image.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
     image.onload = function() {
         let dataURL;
         canvas.height = image.height;
         canvas.width = image.width;
         ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

         // Define the image format here more dynamically
         dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

         // Resolve the promise
         resolve(dataURL);

         // Clear the memory
         canvas = null; 
     };

     image.onerror = function() {
       reject(new Error('createIcon: Can not convert image to base64'));
     };

     // The image will load after setting an src attribute
     image.src = iconURL;
   });
 }
```

Message:

```
 let message = {
   title: 'Batman message',
   text: 'Robin pick my up at my cave'
 };
```

Icon URL:

```
 const iconURL = '/assets/icons/batman_icon128x128.png';
```

Usage example:

```
 // Promise
 createIcon(iconURL).then((dataURL) => {

   // Gecko >= 22
   if(typeof window.Notification === 'function') {
     new Notification(message.title, {
       body: message.text,
       icon: dataURL
     });
   }
   // Gecko < 22
   else if (typeof navigator.mozSetMessageHandler === 'function') {

     let notification = navigator.mozNotification.createNotification(
       message.title,
       message.text,
       dataURL
     );

     notification.show();
   }
 }).catch(function(error) {
   // Rejection
   console.warn(error);
 });
```

Comment: You missed the `+` when you copied the text from mdn. As he's developing for 1.2, using the manifest should work fine. The rest of your solution only makes sense for supporting `FirefoxOS<1.1`